# Create a directive that applies another in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Say I have multiple directives that I use often.

It would be very convenient if I could simply create another directive, 
that would simply apply all the other directives on the very same element I applied it to at once.

I tried looking around, but could not find any straight forward solution to that.

Do note: I don't want to add a wrapping element, I want to apply the other directives to the **same element** that used my directive.

I'd love to know how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Directives can't currently be added/removed dynamically.

I think there are more but these issues seem somewhat related.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11716
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785